# How to pass function as prop to component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that generates input in Form. I'm trying to pass a function to OnChange event, but always getting error

```
import {  FormGroup, FloatingLabel, FormControl } from "react-bootstrap";

const FormInput = (props) =>{ 

return(

    <FormGroup controlId={props.controlId} className="mb-3"> 
    <FloatingLabel label={props.label}>
        <FormControl type={props.type} name={props.controlId} placeholder={props.label} onChange={props.onChange} />
    </FloatingLabel>
</FormGroup>
)

}

export default FormInput;
```

And in my App I'm passing props to Component. Can't figure out how to pass function to get value on input

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
Container,
Row,
Form,
Button,

} from "react-bootstrap";
import FormInput from "./FormInput";
import {  FormGroup, FloatingLabel, FormControl } from "react-bootstrap";


class AddRecipe extends Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  recipeImage: "",
  recipeName: "",
  recipeIngredients: "",
};


this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

}
handleChange = (e) =>{
this.setState({
  [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
});

}

render() {
return (
  <Container>
    <Row>

    
      <Form inline="true" className="mt-5">
        <FormInput
          controlId="recipeImage"
          label="Image URL"
          type="url"
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <FormInput
          controlId="recipeName"
          label="Recipe Name"
          type="text"
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <FormInput
          controlId="recipeIngredients"
          label="Ingredients"
          type="textarea"
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          
        />

        <Button>Add</Button>
      </Form>
    </Row>
  </Container>
);
}
}

export default AddRecipe;
```

How to pass handleChange function as props, so I can write value to my state?

Comment: *"but always getting error"* - What is the error?

Comment: is the error something like, props.onChange is not defined?

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')

Comment: The name of the prop is ```handleChange``` and you try to access ```.onChange``` prop of your props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your component, you define the prop as `onChange`, but in your app, you pass the prop `handleChange`. To fix the error, just change the name of the prop you pass in your app:

```javascript
<FormInput
  controlId="recipeImage"
  label="Image URL"
  type="url" 
  onChange={this.handleChange} 
/>
{/* this `onChange` prop should fix it */}
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I was using a different name for props.

Ater changing

```
 <FormInput
      controlId="recipeIngredients"
      label="Ingredients"
      type="textarea"
      handleChange={this.handleChange}
      
    />
```

to

```
 <FormInput
          controlId="recipeIngredients"
          label="Ingredients"
          type="textarea"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          
        />
```

It fixed issue. Thank you